# Django rest framework Detail not found while deleting

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

i have a a problem deleting an object via API. So i have 2 models, Answer and Vote vote is connected to Answer via foreignKey like this

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    class AnswerScore(models.IntegerChoices):
        add = 1
        subtract = -1

    score = models.IntegerField(choices=AnswerScore.choices)
    answer = models.ForeignKey('Answer', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    user = models.ForeignKey('users.CustomUser', on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('answer', 'user',)

class Answer(models.Model):
    answer = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, default=timezone.now)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    user = models.ForeignKey('users.CustomUser', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    question = models.ForeignKey('Question', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    number_of_points = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    moderate_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Now i have an API endpoint for creating a Vote for user on a particular answer

```
    path('answers/<int:pk>/vote', VoteCreate.as_view()),
```

Looks like this:

```
class VoteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True, default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
    answer = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Vote
        fields = '__all__'


class VoteCreate(ParentKeyAPIView, generics.CreateAPIView):
    model = Vote
    parent_model_field = 'answer_id'
    serializer_class = VoteSerializer

    def perform_create_kwargs(self, **kwargs):
        answer_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        answer = Answer.objects.get(id=int(answer_id))

        if Vote.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, answer=answer).exists():
            old_vote = Vote.objects.get(user=self.request.user, answer=answer)
            answer -= old_vote.score
            answer.save()
            old_vote.delete()

        return super().perform_create_kwargs(user=self.request.user, answer_id=answer_id, **kwargs)
```

Im using the same serializer just like above*

I get an error:
Not Found: /api/v1/answers/55/voteDelete
There is no any traceback, i have checked in fact that in database the Vote with answer_id 55 exists and i can delete them via django-admin but cant via API.
Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing - let's change `get_queryset` to `get_object`, because you want single object. Then instead of `answer_id=self.kwargs['pk']` simplify it to `answer=self.kwargs['pk']`.

Another thing - I think it's might be better to delete old vote while creating new one. You don't need serializer or special view for that. Just add to function creating new `Vote` object in your view:

```
class VoteCreate(...):
    ...
    def perform_create_kwargs(self, **kwargs):
        answer_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        answer = Answer.object.get(id=int(answer_id))

        if Vote.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, answer=answer).exists():
            old_vote = Vote.objects.get(user=self.request.user, answer=answer)
            answer.number_of_points -= old_vote.score
            answer.save()
            old_vote.delete()

        return super().perform_create_kwargs(user=self.request.user, answer_id=answer_id, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Hey!! Thanks for the help, changing get_queryset to get_object has helped! But i still don't understand where should i put the if statement. Do you mean in get_object function? Because my api views are class-based.

Comment: Edited answer. You can try include it in `perform_create_kwargs` method. It's possible that you will need to `import Answer` from your `models`.

Comment: I also edited the question, if you could check if that's what you meant? But it doesn't add new isntance. I actually thought of using pre-delete django signal to Answer so that before the Vote gets deleted if does answer.number_of_points = F('number_of_points) - instance.score, but yeah adding a new instance immediately and clearing the number_of_points for an answer would be convenient.

Comment: Oh, you put it ine the wrong view :) I meant you should drop the idea of `delete` view for changing vote. The function should be in `VoteCreate` class, that I assume is working correctly. Edited to avoid confusion.

Comment: Yeah that's very clever! Youre right, but i get an error of     answer -= old_vote.score
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'Answer' and 'int'
I tried using F expression, but it has no parameter save. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Oh, sorry. You have to use the field of `Answer`, that is keeping score. You didn't provide it, but I assume it's probably `answer.score -= 1`. Unless you are keeping counting score by function. If you provide `Answer` model, I will edit with solid result.

Comment: So yes the main number_of_points is in the Answer model. I'll update the question with answer model as well.

Comment: But yes, answer.number_of_points has worked out. Thank you very much for you help!!! I can't thank you enough